# Github - How local repo know that remote has been deleted?

Tags: git, github, repository

I pushed project to remote git repo. Now I deleted the remote repo. But when I make changes in local repo, it shows files that are changes. I think my local repo does not know that remote repo is deleted.

How can I reset local repo, so that Source control shows no files are changed?

Comment: The presence or absence of other repositories has no effect on *your* repository. *Your* repository is *yours*, it's not a slave of someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the following into the command line, within the project folder:

```
$ rm -rf .git
```

Or to delete .gitignore and .gitmodules if any

Then from the same ex-repository folder, to see if hidden folder .git is still there:

```
$ ls -lah
```